# How to programmatically connect to a particular PC of unknown IP from a WiFi network?

Tags: design, networking

I want to connect and transfer data between a PC and an Android device both of which are on the same local WiFi network.

I cannot use the local IP as such in the code to actually get the connection going because it does not remain constant every time. I know I can set the local IP to be constant but I am looking for a more general solution to the problem.

Having a central server is also not what I'm looking for, because I want to transfer data offline.

I am not an expert on networks as you might have already guessed, so if I am missing something out, let me know. Also is there some API in android that could do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should look at broadcasting. This is technique of sending your packets to all devices (IP's) in a subnet. It would look something like that:

- Android 192.168.0.101: Send message packet to broadcast address
  192.168.0.254
- PC 192.168.0.110: Reply to 192.168.0.101's broadcast message
- Android now knows PC's IP address and can communicate directly

It's really simple. You can find JAVA sample in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999425/simple-udp-broadcast-client-and-server-on-different-machines

Comment: +1 but is this the most efficient way to go about this?

Comment: it is the ONLY way to go about it.

Comment: @Mawg I'm gonna take your word for it then.

Comment: Think about it. If you want to sent a letter (how quaint) to that nice grrrl who smiled at you in the pub lat night, your going to have to walk around town pushing a note throw every letter box asking her to get in touch

Comment: Well, its more similar to asking a postman of giving letters to all the girls in town. One more alternative is phonebook, or in your case - some kind of external site/api (tracker in bitorrent terms).

Comment: Multicast has the potential to be more efficient, though on the same subnet multicast frames will go to all hosts so it's no more efficient than broadcast. Where multicast wins versus broadcast is in its ability to traverse routers.